# Issue with Aiogram: Unable to Get User Input in Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm currently working on a Telegram bot using the Aiogram library in Python. I'm trying to capture user input using the message_handler decorator, but for some reason, it's not working as expected. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import Message

API_TOKEN = ''
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'start')
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Enter your name: ")

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text)
async def get_user_input(message: Message):
    user_input = message.text
    await message.answer(f"Thanks, {user_input}! You've entered your name. Proceed setting a password...")
```

The issue I'm facing is that the get_user_input handler is not getting triggered when the user sends a message after the 'start' command. I expected it to capture any text input from the user, but it's not working as intended.

- I've double-checked my handler registration, and it seems correct.
- The 'start' command is working fine; it's just the get_user_input handler that's not being triggered.

Is there a specific configuration or something I need to add to make the get_user_input handler work correctly?